# Octave IDE DomainMath IDE error

Tags: java, octave

I have installed Octave DomainMath IDE to be able to get a Matlab like environment for Octave. However I am getting this error

```
error: 'javaaddpath' undefined near line 6 column 1
error: 'javaaddpath' undefined near line 6 column 1
 >> pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
 --------------+---------+-----------------------
    java  |   1.2.9 | ...\Octave-3.6.4\share\octave\packages\java-1.2.9.
```

Any ideas how to fix this please ?

Comment: Can you show us that line ?

Comment: What command are you running that gives you this error?

Answer (score 0):

Does following code works in Octave from command prompt?

```
pkg load java
help javaaddpath
```

If it displayed help document,then your java package works correctly,otherwise contact Octave forum. If your java package works correctly,give more details about your OS,Gnu Octave(built for VS2010 or MingW), Complete DMI output text,etc.